# Normal and Depth from Dynamic Cubemap

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

How can I get the depth and normal from secondary reflections by using dynamic cubemap?

Follow my current code:

**Vertex Shader**:

```
#version 130

uniform mat4 osg_ViewMatrixInverse;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    mat4 ModelWorld4x4 = osg_ViewMatrixInverse * gl_ModelViewMatrix;
    mat3 ModelWorld3x3 = mat3( ModelWorld4x4 );
    vec4 WorldPos = ModelWorld4x4 *  gl_Vertex;
    vec3 N = normalize( ModelWorld3x3 * gl_Normal );
    vec3 E = normalize( WorldPos.xyz - cameraPos.xyz );
    gl_TexCoord[1].xyz = reflect( E, N );
}
```

**Fragment Shader**:

```
#version 130

uniform samplerCube cubeMap;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
const float reflect_factor = 0.5;

void main (void)                                                            
{
    vec3 base_color = texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb;
    vec3 cube_color = textureCube(cubeMap, gl_TexCoord[1].xyz).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(cube_color, base_color, reflect_factor).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, @Rabbid76. I want get the depth and normal values from secondary reflections provided by dynamic cubemap. Currently I can get only the first reflections (`positionEyeSpace = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);`
and `normalEyeSpace = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;`).

Comment: Why do you need depth and normals of reflected objects?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to simulate the multipath phenomenon by rasterization, so I need to collect the normal and depth data from reflected objects. Dynamic cubemap is one of the global illumination techniques.

Comment: @Rabbid76 and HolyBlackCat, do you have any tips here?

Comment: Do you have any tips here?